# How to insert a cast conversion into database

Tags: sql, sql-server, casting, varchar

I've been trying to insert a varchar value into a table in SQL using a cast.

The varchar input values has a string datetime format like this:

```
'08/25/2022 03:34:59 PM'
```

The `fechaInicio` column is originally filled with NULL, and the purpose of the stored procedure is to update that column with the `@strDateTime` value sent.

Example of my table [Table_Input]:

| fechaInicio | ID |
| --- | --- |
| NULL | 2 |

If I just do a

```
SELECT CAST('08/25/2022 03:34:59 PM' AS DATETIME)
```

it actually works and shows me the correct casting in the message window. But the problem is when I try to update into the table.

I removed my try-except commands to see the error.

If I call the stored procedure like this

```
[SP_Table_Input_Get_Series] '08/25/2022 03:34:59 PM', 2
```

I get the following error:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SP_Table_Input_Get_Series, Line 34 [Batch Start Line 13]
> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

My stored procedure is something like this:

```sql
PROCEDURE [SP_Table_Input_Get_Series]
    @strDateTime NVARCHAR(50),
    @cId int
AS
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    UPDATE [Table_Input]
    SET 
       ---fechaInicio =convert(datetime, @strDateTime, 5),
       ---fechaInicio = N'select cast(@strDateTime as datetime)'
       fechaInicio = CAST(@strDateTime AS datetime)
    WHERE id = @cId     -- the where clause works fine

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

All the 3 options (including commented ones in the stored procedure) didn't work.

Also a constraint is I cannot modify the column type to `varchar` or any other type.

I will really appreciated if someone can help me find a solution.

I'm running the stored procedure directly in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: PLease edit your question, and add the following: (1) @strOrigen NVARCHAR(50) value, (2) `CREATE TABLE [Table_Input] ...`

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky I just updated the names.

Comment: Do they have 89 seconds in a minute?

Comment: If you have control over the format of the source string you might have better luck using `'2022-08-25T15:34:59'`, otherwise consider using [`CONVERT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql#date-and-time-styles) with a specific Date and Time style code instead of `CAST()`.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: @DanielaLuna as already requested we need a [MRE] because since you say the column is not being updated, that tells us that the issue is not with the date format, but rather with your update statement or your calling code. Please create a DBFiddle to demonstrate the issue, and tell us from which platform you are calling this SP.

Comment: @DaleK I hope the modifications made can give a better context :)

Comment: @DanielaLuna not at all... there is nothing in the provided information which indicates why an update would silently fail. As already asked multiple time, please create a [MRE] i.e. the entire code we need to reproduce the issue, in DBFiddle would be great.

Comment: Like [this dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=90d33e2db5368ff938dc80eafd5825c3) which shows that the code as posted works!

Comment: You had a try/catch block to swallow the error - but didn't show us - a whole bunch of us have wasted our valuable time trying to solve this for you without the correct information.

Comment: @DaleK My apologies for the missing the try/catch. ```convert(DATETIME, @strDateTime, 101)``` gets me the same error as the one I posted in the question.

Comment: If this `select convert(DATETIME, @strDateTime, 101)` works and the update doesn't, then there is something else going on that you haven't showed us. Do you have any triggers?

Comment: @DaleK I don't have any triggers :( and that is actually all that i have.

Comment: Run this `DBCC USEROPTIONS;` and post the results.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following solution.

As @AlwaysLearning pointed out, I changed 89 to 59 seconds.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, fechaInicio DATETIME2(0));
INSERT @tbl (fechaInicio) VALUES
(GETDATE());
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @strDateTime VARCHAR(50) = '08/25/2022 03:34:59 PM';

-- before
SELECT * FROM @tbl;

UPDATE @tbl
SET fechaInicio = convert(DATETIME2(0), @strDateTime, 101)
where ID = 1;

-- after
SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```

**Output**

| ID | fechaInicio |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-08-25 15:34:59 |

Comment: datetime has been deprecated for some time.

Comment: @MitchWheat, I concur.

Comment: @MitchWheat `datetime` is not deprecated at all

Comment: Sorry my sql knowledge is basic and I'm quite confused with your answer. As far as I understand @tbl is like a temp table? I did try using the convert instruction in my SP, but still no success to update the column. Thank you

Comment: @DanielaLuna, I provided you a minimal reproducible example. You copy it to SSMS as-is, run it there, and it works.

Comment: @honeybadger: perhaps deprecated is too strong: "Use the time, date, datetime2 and datetimeoffset data types for new work. These types align with the SQL Standard. They are more portable. time, datetime2 and datetimeoffset provide more seconds precision. datetimeoffset provides time zone support for globally deployed applications." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: with the emphasis on "Use the time, date, datetime2 and datetimeoffset data types for new work"

Comment: I prefer to use datetimeoffset data type all the time.  One single state of Florida has two time zones.

Comment: @DaleK Sorry i will update. But I mean that after executing the Stored Procedure, the fechaInicio column remains as how it was before running the SP.